# finding $\lim_{h\to 0 }\int \vert f(x+h)-f(x)\vert ^pdx$ when $f\in L^p$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f\in L^p$, $p\in [1,\infty)$. My naive attempt is $\lim_{h\to 0}\int \vert f(x+h)-f(x)\vert ^pdx=\lim_{h\to 0}\int \vert \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\vert ^ph^p=\int \vert f'(x)\vert ^ph^p=0$, but I am not sure if $f$ is differentiable as it is not required for $L^p$ functions. Since $f$ may not be differentiable, I may not necessarily be able to push the limit through the integral. If $f$ is not differentiable, how do I deal with the integrand? Not sure what trick/construction is needed here.

Comment: if *f* is in $L_p$, $|f(x+h)-f(x)|^p$ <$|f(x+h)|^p + |f(x)|^p$ By Minkowski. Which are both bounded since *f* $\in$ $L_p$ If *f* is not differentiable, or f has a lot of its mass concentrated on a few single values, the derivative approach doesn't work. If f is continuous, then you get the limit is 0. If it is not, it reduces to a sum over all discontinuities. At least that's my guess/ intuition.

Answer (score 1):

Prove it in two steps:

1. Prove it for $f$ a continuous function with compact support (you will need to use the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous.)
2. Since the space of continuous functions with compact support is dense in $L^p([0,\infty))$, a density argument gives the result in the general case.